# Anonymous union inside struct vs. named union type?

Tags: c, struct, unions

While reading [the documentation of BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/ns-bluetoothapis-_bluetooth_address), I encountered the following code:

```
typedef struct _BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS {
  union {
    BTH_ADDR ullLong;
    BYTE     rgBytes[6];
  };
} BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_STRUCT;
```

This got me wondering; if we define a structure with the only member being the (anonymous) union, what is the difference between this and creating a named union type?

```
union BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_STRUCT {
    BTH_ADDR ullLong;
    BYTE     rgBytes[6];
};
```

It looks like those two would be the same, so I guess I am missing something. Why use the former and not the latter?

Comment: These are not equal, as the second union should be `typedef union { .... } BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_STRUCT` also defining a typedef. Itsn't the code you linked about C++?

Comment: @KamilCuk *Isn't the code you linked about C++?* – No. That's C.

Comment: @KamilCuk so using typedef would make those two equal? What is the difference?  If you know the answer to the question, please write it!

Answer (score 2):

@Swordfish describes an important difference with respect to future maintenance and development of your code.  But even if we consider only the semantics of the two alternatives as they stand, there are a few inequivalences between a union and a structure whose only member is an anonymous union.  Some of these are distinctions without any practical difference, however.

- the two types are not "compatible" in the standard's sense of that term, which roughly means that you may not use an object of one of those types where an object of the other is required.
- The tagged union may have a member structure with a flexible array member.  The anonymous union inside a structure may not have such a member (C2011, [6.7.2.1/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3)).
- You may use the `offsetof` macro (C2011, [7.19/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3)) with the structure and the members of its anonymous union, but not with the tagged union.
- Although the standard requires pointers to structure types to have the same representation as each other, and it requires pointers to union types to have the same representation as each other, it *does not* require pointers to structures to have the same representation as pointers to unions (C2011, [6.2.5/28](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28)).
- There is a special provision for accessing the common initial sequence of structures that are members of the same union (c2011, [6.5.2.3/6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p6)).  It does not apply to unions that are members of a union.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason that comes to my mind for using a `struct` containing an anonymous `union` instead of an `union` is, that additional members can be added to the `struct` in the future. There is no way doing that with an `union`.

Comment: But you could change the union into a struct with the same result.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: That means other modules referencing the object, as with `union foo *pointer` (so they have a pointer to the object but do not know its contains), have to be recompiled. If it were originally declared as a struct containing an anonymous union, new members can be added without rebuilding other modules. If the structure is exported by a library that wants to maintain compatibility, that is important.

Comment: @Eric. The original is a typedef.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yes, but a pointer to the structure or union can still be made visible by a declaration such as `union foo *pointer`. E.g., the OP may have shown us the `typedef` that defines it internally to a library they are publishing, but there may also be a header that exports a declaration of a pointer to the structure or union.